# Display a pop-up message to a linux computer using it's IP and port?

Tags: linux, popup, message, ubuntu-16.04

So basically, I have the public IP of a Linux computer, what I want to do is, just display something like a pop-up message to that computer through my Linux machine via the internet. I don't want a two-way chat, just want to message the other computer some text and I don't want to setup anything on the recipient computer!

Comment: As far as i know this requires a kind of program to be installed on  the target; This is why trojans were made .

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/309961/linux-how-to-send-message-to-local-user-logged-into-x11